# Я делаю небольшой текстовый виджет на основе tkinter.Text в python 3, для показа сообщения

Tags: python, tkinter, текст

Можно ли как ни будь сделать так чтобы выравнивание в нем делалось в на всю строку.

Пример невозможного кода:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
txt = tk.Text(root)
txt.pack()
txt.insert(tk.END, 'Message')
txt.tag_add('msgtag', 1.0, tk.END)
txt.tag_configure('msgtag', justify = 'justify') # Но я смотрел на https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/text.htm но там justify можно поставить только как right | left | center
txt.config(justify = 'justify') # или так , но так нельзя тоже
root.mainloop()
```

Может есть какой ни будь способ вставить пробелы между словами? Или узнать сколько пробелов в строке не хватает?

Comment: а форматировать Message заранее не вариант ?  '{: ^50}'.format('rovno centr')

Comment: В Tkinter нет ничего, что могло бы выравнивать текст одновременно по левому и правому полям.

Comment: @Интик желательно чтобы это сохраняло форматирование при увеличении размера виджета, когда например ты делаешь .pack(expand = True, fill = 'both')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Средствами tkinter нет нормального способа это сделать

Comment: К проверяющим: это и есть ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Это и есть ответ на вопрос

Answer (score 1):

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
txt = tk.Text(root)
txt.pack()
txt.insert(tk.END, 'Message')
text_content = txt.get(1.0, 'end')
txt.tag_config('center', justify=tk.CENTER)
txt.delete(1.0, tk.END)
txt.insert(tk.INSERT, text_content, 'center')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]